# How do I test for the percentage of bold text on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, unit-testing, selenium, cucumber

I have an instance where I need to test how page content is styled (not necessarily only with CSS).

For example, a test (cucumber) I would like to write is:

In order to standardize text weight
As a webmaster
I want to be told the percentage of bold text on the page

The problem is, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to actually generate this result.  Looking at various HTML testing frameworks (Selenium, Watir, Capybara), it seems like I can only test for the presence of tags or the presence of css classes, and not the calculated visual result.

In Firebug, I can see the calculated CSS result (which works for <strong>, <b>, and `font-weight:bold` definitions), but I need to be able to put this into a testing framework to run under CI.

Comment: "Percentage" by area? by word count?

Answer (score 1):

In Watir, you can get access to an elements font-weight by directly accessing the win32ole object. For example:

```
ie.div(:index, 1).document.currentStyle.fontWeight
```

This will give you a numbers representing the weight as described in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

What I think you would then need to do is iterate through all elements on the page checking what its fontWeight is and how much text is in the element. The way you do that will depend on the page you are testing.

**Solution 1 - If all text is in divs that are leaf nodes:**

If all your text is in leaf nodes like this:

```
<body>
    <div style='font-weight:bold'>Bold</div>
    <div>Plain</div>
</body>
```

You could easily do:

```
bold_text = 0
plain_text = 0
ie.divs.each{ |x| 
  if x.document.currentStyle.fontWeight >= 700
    bold_text += x.text.length
  else
    plain_text += x.text.length
  end
}
```

**Solution 2 - If styles interact or using multiple elements:**

If not all of the text is in leaf nodes or you use other tags like `<b>` (see example HTML below), you would need a more complicated check. This is due to .text returning all text in the element, including its children elements.

```
<body>
  <div style='font-weight:normal'>
    Start
    <div style='font-weight:bold'>Bold1</div>
    <div style='font-weight:bold'>Bold2</div>
    End
  </div>
  <b>Bold Text</b>
</body>
```

In this case, I believe the following works for most cases (but may need refinement):

```
#Counting letters, but you could easily change to words
bold_count = 0
plain_count = 0

#Check all elements, though you can change this to restrict to a particular containing element if desired.
node_list = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("*")

0.upto(node_list.length-1) do |i|
    #Name the node so it is easier to work with.
    node = node_list["#{i}"]

    #Determine if the text for the current node is bold or not.
    #Note that this works in IE. You might need to modify for other browsers.
    if node.currentStyle.fontWeight >= 700
        bold = true
    else
        bold = false
    end

    #Go through the childNodes. If the node is text, count it. Otherwise ignore.
    node.childNodes.each do |child|
        unless child.nodeValue.nil? 
            if bold
                bold_count += child.nodeValue.length
            else
                plain_count += child.nodeValue.length
            end
        end
    end

end

#Determine number of characters that are bold and not. These can be used to determine your percentage.
puts bold_count
puts plain_count
```

It is not a very Watir-like solution, but hopefully solves your problem.